# How to remove characters in a string that meet an exact condition in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of various strings and I would like to remove a component that satisfies a certain condition. For instance from `2012/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089` I would like to remove /EPS.

I have tried using gsub, however all Ps are removed. I would like to keep any other characters like /,E,P,S individually, however want to remove /EPS if it appears in this exact way. I would like to do this to every element of a vector say V, containing all the strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sub("\\/EPS", "", V)`

Comment: You should share the code you tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
term <- '2012/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089'

gsub(pattern = '/EPS', x = term, replacement = "")
```

Output:

```
> gsub(pattern = '/EPS', x = term, replacement = "")
[1] "2012.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089"
```

Comment: Any idea how I can use this function for multiple characters I would liek to remove?e.g. '/EPS' and '/PPS', so that I dont have to apply the function for each strings of characters I want to remove. Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend writing out another line of similar code instead of all in one. Might not be ideal, but it makes the code much more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: That is what I did in the end, not too much to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what went wrong with your code, which you never showed us, but `sub` should work here:

```
x <- "2012/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089"
sub("/EPS", "", x)

[1] "2012.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089"
```

I also don't know what your exact replacement logic is, e.g what are the conditions for which an `/EPS` should be replaced.  Depending on that, the above pattern might have to change.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to match the pattern `/EPS` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("/EPS", "", V)
#[1] "2012.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089"
```

#### data

```
V <- "2012/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089"
```

Comment: Forward slash is not a regex metacharacter, and therefore should not require any special escaping.

Answer (score 0):

`stringr` solution:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(string,"/EPS")
[1] "2012.WCR.PL6.NORM.0089"
```